# [Android]How to store facebook post for showing it later

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating an android application where I need to fetch the /home feeds into a database and then show it to the user whenever it is requested.

I need to create an inflater layout, containing facebook feeds and inflate it in another activity.

So there are two parts to this question.

1. How should I store the post into database.
   I can normally store the post into the database using the post attributes mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), I just needed some view on this.
2. The important question is how can I create the facebook post ui using previously stored data. I need to use this post ui for later purposes(like inflating to other activities.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ya create database as you requirement and and store data ther and you can whenever you need or you can store it into class as your wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch post or feeds from facebook with the api and can create a SQlite database in android with all the required fields you think you will need later.

Create a table with required columns and store all feeds into the table
Create a xml or layout file as per your design requirements and later on you can set this xml on activity where you can fetch all feeds from Sqlite with appropriate query.

Comment: The problem is how can I create the facebook post ui using previously stored data? I do not want to create any ui, but the ui similar to a facebook post in native fb application.

Comment: I am not clear with your problem. You can redirect user to FB app if you want to use FB native app UI or you can use similar theme and can create your own UI and can fetch data from SQlite you previously stored.